# How to save numpy array as .raw image?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have some array, let's say `a = np.asarray([[10, 50], [30, 60]])`
And I know that colors of pixels are `colors = np.asarray([['G', 'R'], ['B', 'G']])`
I want to save the image in .raw (or .dng) format. How do I do this?

Comment: Could you be a bit clearer about what your numbers in your array are please? Is it supposed to be a 2x2 pixel? What is the 10 please? 10 what? A sample image where the height, width and number of colour channels are all different is much easier to understand than a 2x2 pixel 2-channel image!

Comment: Why do you want to save this as DNG? DNG is an extremely portable, expressive format for high-resolution and non-standard data that often requires sophisticated deBayering and calibration. Is that your data? Or do you mean you want raw pixels without headers or other extraneous info? What are hou you trying to achieve here please?

Comment: @mark-setchell I have raw files but they saved for unknown me reason in png files. Basically they are like white-black pictures, but actually they are raw files. And I need to do demosaicing for them, but I can't open them in for example rawpy library. First array in my answer `a` is 2x2 picture, and each number corresponds to how much color of corresponding colors of `colors` is presented in the corresponding pixel

Comment: I'm confused. The title of your question implies you want to **write** a raw file, but your comment implies you have raw files, which are somehow PNG files, that you cannot **read**.  Your 2-channel 2x2 pixel isn't helping much either.

Comment: @mark-setchell I read PNG files, I get some let's say 512x512 one channel numpy array. Then, I want to write this array to .raw file. I assume that Bayer filter is `[['G', 'R'], ['B', 'G']]`

Comment: You said they were colour files, but now you say they are single channel?

Comment: How about sharing the input file so we can see if it is raw or PNG, or single channel or colour? And also providing a link to a web page that describes the type of raw file you want to make, please?

Comment: I think, the answer is already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535687/write-a-raw-binary-file-with-numpy-array-data/10536046#10536046?newreg=18c512a38c4e4db8bc74c29c3833709a).

Answer (score 0):

I think the [rawpy](https://pypi.org/project/rawpy/) library might be your friend here, I believe the raw_image type is just implemented through numpy arrays.